# Traffic with Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The number of cars that cross an intersection during any interval of length t minutes between 3:00 pm and 4:00 pm has a Poisson distribution with mean t. Let W be the time that has passed after 3:00 pm and before the first car crosses the intersection. What is the probability of W being less than two minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The probability that $W\ge 2$, or equivalently the probability that $W\gt 2$, is the probability that $0$ cars go through the intersection in $2$ minutes.

Comment: Let X be the rv of the number of cars that cross the intersection during any interval of length t minutes between 3:00 pm and 4:00 pm. So $P(W< 2) = 1 -P(2\leq W)= 1- P(X=0)= 1 - e^{-t}$ ?

Comment: It is equal to $1-e^{-2}$.

Comment: But why do we take t= 2? Isn't t a fixed constant?

Comment: It says the mean in $t$ minutes is $t$. So the parameter $\lambda$ (the mean) for $2$ minutes is $2$.

Comment: I don't think it says that, it says "any interval of length $t$" and "mean $t$" - this says to me that $t$ is a constant. If so, then it is equal to $1-e^{-\frac{2}{t}}$.

Comment: Brcause of properties of the Poisson, parameter $1$ for an interval of length $1$ minute is equivalent to parameter $t$ in any interval of length $t$.  OP can decide what to do. If it is a homework question, any answer other than $1-e^{-2}$ will get marked as wrong.

Comment: It is not a homework question, but I'd like to know what properties are those?  Because I'm really struggling to see why the mean for 2 minutes is 2.

Comment: The underlying assumption of the Poisson is that the probability of an "event" in the time interval from $s$ to $s+\Delta s$, divided by $\delta s$, has limit the constant $\lambda$ as $\Delta s\to 0$. More formally, one uses the derivative. Furthermore, the probability of more than one event goes to $0$ faster than $\Delta s$, and events over disjoint intervals are independent. One consequence of this is that if the number of events in an interval of length $a$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, and $Y$ is the number of events in an interval of length $ka$, then (to be Cont.)

Comment: (Cont) $Y$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $k\lambda$. (The parameter is the mean.) So if the number of events in an interval of length $t$ is Poisson mean $t$, then the number of events in an interval of length $1$ is Poisson mean $1$, and the number of events in an interval of length $2$ is Poisson mean (parameter) $2$. If $W$ is the number of events in an interval of length $2$, then $\Pr(W=w)=e^{-2}\frac{2^w}{w!}$. We used the case $w=0$.